# KVM Online-Backup of a Windows-Machine

Tags: backup, linux-kvm, virsh

I implemented a bash script which is backing up my VMs. 
Basically I am doing the following steps:

1. Create a snapshot of the target VM
2. Backup the disk of the target VM
3. Merge the changes back to the disk

Now I tested the backups and noticed, that the disks of the machines are not fully consistent. The Windows machine is starting with a chkdisk and recovers some files. I understand that this is especially the case, if step 1 happens during a write.

However, all backups done so far, are booting but I am afraid that there are cases where the backup won't boot.

I am especially worried about the windows machines.

Are these worries justified?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure your backups are consistent, you need to tell the VM to put the filesystem into a consistent (quiesced) state. On both Linux and Windows this requires some support for quiescing the filesystem, and this is provided by the [qemu guest agent](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-using_the_qemu_guest_virtual_machine_agent_protocol_cli-libvirt_commands).

Make sure have the qemu guest agent running in each VM. Then, take your snapshot by adding `--quiesce` to the snapshot command, i.e.:

```
virsh snapshot-create --quiesce <domain>
```

You can also freeze and thaw the filesystem manually, without necessarily taking a snapshot, with `virsh domfsfreeze` and `virsh domfsthaw`. Use these if you are taking snapshots outside of libvirt, e.g. with ZFS or with SAN storage.